# Git conflict while rebasing code multiple times

Tags: git

I have following situation.I changed file1.sh and pushed the code in the git.I forgot rebase the code before pushing.
Reviewer rebased it again two times so i have following
Change-Id:
I44ee8ff5d87e181b5f9dfe6a217ec409f41787c4

```
Patch Set 1
 6a6f6d6aa5f6bf778e5b03b32733dd10068f1ad6 (gitweb)
Patch Set 2
 b4e9e9df44eb0bc2b18c7eebaf12df20041831b3 (gitweb)
Patch Set 3
 5f0b9afb9199ddb70e0684be4406732ab7b023a3 (gitweb)
```

In gerrit it is showing patch 3 merged

To get latest code I ran command

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

I got rebase conflict in file1.sh

I tried with

```
git pull
```

I am getting merger conflict in file1.sh

I ran

```
git log origin/master..HEAD


commit 6a6f6d6aa5f6bf778e5b03b32733dd10068f1ad6
Author: Vik <vik@test.com>
Date:   Wed May 4 11:21:55 2016 +0530

Admin ui Upgrade change

Change-Id: I44ee8ff5d87e181b5f9dfe6a217ec409f41787c4
```

I want to get latest code, how to get latest udpated code ?
Why 6a6f6d6aa5f6bf778e5b03b32733dd10068f1ad6 is showing as local commit only even though changeset is merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try *git fetch origin master && git checkout -b newbranch FETCH_HEAD* and you get the latest code. use *git log* to check if the newbranch has patch set 3.

if you still want to update your local branch by *git pull*, you have to do something first. you local branch's HEAD is patch set 1 but the gerrit's branch has patch set 3 instead. *git reset HEAD^ --hard* to abandon the patch set 1 and then *git pull*, it's a fast-forward merge and your local branch's HEAD is now the patch set 3.

always remember, if your local commit is not submitted into gerrit in the end, just abandon it and reset to its parent in the local.